# Spark "can't extract value" after reading from parquet

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet

I have a *Spark* DataFrame that I am storing on *Amazon S3* in parquet format for later use. Using the DataFrame before storing it is not an issue. I have also done this numerous times before with the same DataFrame (just containing an older version of the same data).

When I read the most recent DataFrame from the parquet file, however, I get the following error after trying to execute any operation on it:

`AnalysisException: u"Can't extract value from <always_the_same_arbirary_column_name>#<arbitrary_number>;"`

My concern is less the underlying issue (I think it is a fair assumption that one of the data values can't be serialized into *parquet* format and corrupts the DataFrame) but rather how to debug this and find the faulty element.

I am using *PySpark* and would only reluctantly resort to Scala due to infrastructure reasons, so happy to hear if you have some nice suggestions.

**UPDATE**

The code that throws the error.

```
joined_features_parquet_name = 'survey_takers_joined_features.parquet' 
sdf_features_raw = spark.read.parquet(s3_path + joined_features_parquet_name) 
sdf_features_raw.show(5)
```

Comment: can you share the code generating the error?

Comment: Sure:

`joined_features_parquet_name = 'survey_takers_joined_features.parquet'
sdf_features_raw = spark.read.parquet(s3_path + joined_features_parquet_name)
sdf_features_raw.show(5)`

Comment: @Westermann - if you have additional information such as code, you should edit your question instead of adding it as a comment.